# How to set inline style rule with eslint?

Tags: react-native, eslint, eslintrc

I create a React Native project the version is `0.62.2`

I change `eslintrc.js` as below

```
module.exports = {
  parser:'babel-eslint',
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    ... my other rules
    "react-native/no-inline-styles": 1,
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", {
      "no-inline-styles": false
    }],
  },
};
```

I hope my style code like this `{{ flex: 1, marginTop: 5 }}` not `{{flex:1,marginTop:5}}`

But my warrning shows info:

```
(property) FlexStyle.marginTop?: React.ReactText
Inline style: { flex: 1, marginTop: 5 }eslint(react-native/no-inline-styles)
Replace `·flex:1,·marginTop:5·` with `flex:·1,·marginTop:·5`eslintprettier/prettier
```

[image]

I have no idea how to set inline styles space and how to fix the prettier problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your configuration is missing prettier in the plugins' array.
Make sure to correctly use eslint to run prettier by reading [prettier's documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html#eslint).

Prettier has a rule for object literals spacing called [bracket spacing](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-spacing), but note that it is set to true by default.

Comment: Thanks Sal, I use Visual Studio Code , I disable my preiiter and I had set `"prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
}` with my settings.json, it still shows the error :(

Comment: Thanks, I find I have a `.prettierrc.js` file block my setting. Fix the issue now. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

the value should be 0, to set it to false. So your rules object should look like this:

```
rules: {
    ... my other rules
    "react-native/no-inline-styles": 0,
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", {
      "no-inline-styles": false
    }],  
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you have mentioned where to implement or file name.

Answer (score 9):

make change to file: .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'react-native/no-inline-styles': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
        'no-shadow': 'off',
        'no-undef': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use disable rule functionality by ESLint

```js
// eslint-disable-line react-native/no-inline-styles
```

For more info visit https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules

Comment: Thanks for response, but I need use no-inline-styles.

Comment: is there any way to define it globally in the project instead of putting it on top of each file?